# Handling Empty Date Time Field When Parsing Xml With XmlReader C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, xmlreader

Hi i'm reading a xml file with XmlReader, i have fields in xml file like:

```
     <Row>
        <Column0>A</Column0>
        <Column1>B</Column1>
        <Column2>C</Column2>
        <Column3>D</Column3>
        <Column4>E</Column4>
        <Column5>F</Column5>
        <Column6>G</Column6>

        <Column7>2017-07-21T00:00:00</Column7>
        <Column8></Column8>
        <Column9>2017-08-19T00:00:00</Column9>
    </Row>
```

and i'm reading specific columns from xml file and store them into a string builder with:

```
public static StringBuilder output2 = new StringBuilder();

reader.ReadToFollowing("Column4");

output2.AppendLine(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
```

Some columns are DateTime and i'm reading DateTime columns with:

```
output4.AppendLine(reader.ReadElementContentAsDateTime().ToShortDateString());
```

But if DateTime typed column empty like "Column8", i'm getting " The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value." error.

I'm really hoping some of you can help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks, regards.

Answer (score 1):

You should use null or empty check.

```
var result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.ReadElementContentAsString())
             ? ""
             : reader.ReadElementContentAsDateTime().ToShortDateString();
```

but my suggestion is to use xdocument for xml operations.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i've already tried null or empty check but i'll try to do it with xdocument.